# Change the opacity on a fraction of each stacked geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked-chart, geom-col

Using the following data frame I aim to stack all x values by group using geom_bar or geom_col and fill them by subgroup.

```
 dat <- data.frame(group = c(rep("H", 4), rep("T",4)), subgroup = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 2),
               x = c(100, 10, 80, 50, 40, 50, 80, 70),
               y = c(20, 5, 50, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50))
```

But I also want to fill each stacked x value with their corresponding y value. However when I use the following code I get the following bar plot.

```
 dat %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = group, y = x, fill = subgroup)) +
   geom_col(alpha = .5) +
   geom_col(aes(x = group, y = y, fill = subgroup), alpha = 1)
```

[image: Bar plot of x values by group stack filled by subgroup]

Can anyone help me to fill a fraction of each subgroup with the y values please? All I have been able to get is an overlapped stack of y values, but not mapped to each color.

I have tried grouping the values and adding a key. however I am stuck with the previous plot

Comment: Please can you add a sketch of how you want the plot to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use geom_rect for this.

If I may put in my 2 cents worth: The result is a fairly clattered visual. I think there might be other options out there to show your fractions. I think my favoured way would to use facets. This is not only making the fraction idea much clearer, and way more intuitive, but is also way simpler to code. See below

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(group = c(rep("H", 4), rep("T",4)), subgroup = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 2),
                  x = c(100, 10, 80, 50, 40, 50, 80, 70),
                  y = c(20, 5, 50, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50))
## width for rects
w <- .45
dat %>%
  ## because it is stacking in reverse alphbetic order
  arrange(group, desc(subgroup)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(frac_ymin = lag(cumsum(x), default = 0), 
         frac_ymax = frac_ymin + y, 
         ## group needs to be numeric for geom_rect
         group = as.integer(factor(group, levels = c("H", "T")))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = x, fill = subgroup)) +
  geom_col(alpha = .5) +
## now use geom_rect instead
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = group - w, xmax = group + w, 
               ymin = frac_ymin, ymax = frac_ymax, 
               fill = subgroup), alpha = 1)
```

[image]

### Suggestion to use facets instead

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(group = c(rep("H", 4), rep("T",4)), subgroup = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 2),
                  x = c(100, 10, 80, 50, 40, 50, 80, 70),
                  y = c(20, 5, 50, 20, 20, 10, 40, 50))

## you can use your old code, just add a facet!
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = x, fill = subgroup)) +
  geom_col(alpha = .5) +
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = y, fill = subgroup), alpha = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~subgroup)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this tjebo. It does look more intuitive when using facets. Really appreciate the input.                             Dan